# Erro ao fazer upload de nova versão de um apk no google play console

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, apk, google-play

Tenho um aplicativo já publicado e quero publicar uma nova versão. 
Ao fazer o upload do apk estou recebendo esse erro:

[image: Erro google play console]

> O envio falhou 
>   O APK ou Android App Bundle precisa ter o nome de
>   pacote com.panterafood.alternativa.

"com.panterafood.alternativa" É O NOME DO PACOTE. O apk esta sendo compilado com o nome certo, por isso esse erro não está fazendo sentido para mim.

[image: informações do apk]

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?
Como posso entrar em contato com o google para eu ver se podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver deletando as pastas bin e obj do projeto do android. Dei um rebuild e consegui fazer o upload!

Answer (score 2):

Olá, tudo bem!?

> reveja o package em app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.exemplo.projeto"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "R15.0c"
}
```

Uma dica, entre no seu app na Google play e verifique o nome do pacote, se é o mesmo do applicationId. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que fizer tudo, de um rebuild no projeto, gere o novo .apk, entre na Google play e remova da biblioteca de artefato essa versao que deu erro.

Abraços.

Comment: Estou trabalhando com Xamarin, não tenho o build.gradle... No AndroidManifest o nome do pacote esta certo, é o mesmo nome que esta na google play...